# Derby DB can't able to start the network server automatically

Tags: derby

[Derby error on Windows 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XD17.jpg)

I have installed both 64 bit and 32 bit JDK's. Can't able to start the derby DB.

Answer (score 0):

Derby 10.15 is for use with Java 9 and higher.

You are using Java 8.

You have two choices:

1. Upgrade your Java to Java 9
2. Get [Derby 10.14](http://db.apache.org/derby/releases/release-10.14.2.0.cgi), which supports Java 8

Note that on the [Derby downloads page](http://db.apache.org/derby/derby_downloads.html), the available releases are grouped by Java version.